# Wrong parameters error in extended Exception class in PHP 7.0

Tags: php, exception, slim, php-7

I'm building a REST API using Slim Framework, on PHP 7.0 (Ubuntu 16.04). For proper exception handling, I extended the base `\Exception` class as follows :

```
namespace App\Exceptions;

class AppException extends \Exception
{

}
```

Then I use this as a base exception for all the application exceptions. For all exceptions that have a JSON response to be given to the user, I wrote another class :

```
namespace App\Exceptions;


use Slim\Container;
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

class JsonApiException extends AppException
{

    private $params = [
        "message" => "",
        "code" => 0,
        "previous" => null,
        "api" => [
            "message" => "",
            "code" => "",
            "status" => 200
        ]
    ];

    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        $this->params = array_merge_recursive($this->params, $params);
        parent::__construct($this->params["message"], 0, $this->params["previous"]);
    }

    public function getApiMessage() {
        return $this->params["api"]["message"];
    }

    public function getApiCode() {
        return $this->params["api"]["code"];
    }

    public function getHttpStatusCode() {
        return $this->params["api"]["status"];
    }

    public function shouldBeLogged() {
        return false;
    }

    public function log(Container $container, Request $request) {
        if(!$this->shouldBeLogged()) return;
        $logger = $container->get('logger.info');
        $logger->info($this, array_merge($request->getHeaders(), [
            "method" => $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"],
            "time" => $_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME"],
            "query_string" => $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"],
            "host" => $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"],
            "referer" => $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"],
            "user_agent" => $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"],
            "ip" => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            "uri" => $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
        ]));
    }

    public function httpRespond(Response $response) {
        return $response->withJson([
            "error" => true,
            "errors" => [
                "server" => [[
                    "code" => $this->getApiCode(),
                    "message" => $this->getApiMessage()
                ]]
            ]
        ], $this->getHttpStatusCode());
    }

}
```

Then I use this as a base exception for all JSON errors. I'm using the following error to let the client know that the e-mail address it provided for registration already exists.

```
namespace App\Exceptions\Validation\User;

use App\Exceptions\JsonApiException;

class EmailAlreadyUsedException extends JsonApiException
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct([
            "message" => "The e-mail provided by the exception has already been used",
            "api" => [
                "message" => "The provided e-mail address has already been used",
                "code" => "EmailAlreadyUsed"
            ],
            "previous" => null
        ]);
    }

}
```

Whenever the error occurs, I add it to another custom exception to enable responding with multiple errors at once during validation :

```
namespace App\Exceptions;


use Slim\Http\Response;

class JsonApiMultipleException extends JsonApiException
{

    private $httpStatusCode = 200;
    private $exceptions = [];

    public function __construct($httpStatusCode = 200, \Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct([]);
        $this->httpStatusCode = 200;
    }

    public function setHttpStatusCode(int $code) {
        $this->httpStatusCode = $code;
    }

    public function add(string $param, JsonApiException $exception) {
        if(!array_key_exists($param, $this->exceptions)) {
            $this->exceptions[$param] = [];
        }
        $this->exceptions[$param][] = $exception;
    }

    public function length() {
        $len = 0;
        foreach ($this->exceptions as $param => $exceptions) {
            $len += count($exceptions);
        }
        return $len;
    }

    public function map() {
        $mapped = [];
        foreach ($this->exceptions as $param => $exceptions) {
            $mapped[$param] = array_map(function (JsonApiException $exception) {
                return [
                    "code" => $exception->getApiCode(),
                    "message" => $exception->getApiMessage()
                ];
            }, $exceptions);
        }
        return $mapped;
    }

    public function getExceptions() {
        return $this->exceptions;
    }

    public function httpRespond(Response $response)
    {
        return $response->withJson([
            "error" => true,
            "errors" => $this->map()
        ], $this->httpStatusCode);
    }

}
```

But when I throw this exception during validation () :

```
namespace App\Validators;

use App\Exceptions\Validation\User\EmailAlreadyUsedException;
use App\Exceptions\Validation\User\InvalidEmailException;
use App\Exceptions\Validation\User\InvalidFirstNameException;
use App\Exceptions\Validation\User\InvalidLastNameException;
use App\Exceptions\Validation\User\InvalidPasswordException;
use Respect\Validation\Validator as v;

class UserValidator extends Validator
{

    //...

    private function validateEmail() {

        //Validate e-mail
        if(!v::stringType()->email()->validate($this->user->getEmail())) {
            $this->exception->add('email', new InvalidEmailException());
        }

        //Check if e-mail already used
        if(\UserQuery::create()->filterByEmail($this->user->getEmail())->count() > 0) {
            $this->exception->add('email', new EmailAlreadyUsedException());
        }
    }

    //...

}
```

It throws the following exception :

```
[Thu Jun 30 05:42:47 2016] Slim Application Error:
Type: Error
Message: Wrong parameters for App\Exceptions\Validation\User\EmailAlreadyUsedException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]])
File: /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Exceptions/JsonApiException.php
Line: 33
Trace: #0 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Exceptions/JsonApiException.php(33): Exception->__construct(Array, 0, Array)
#1 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Exceptions/Validation/User/EmailAlreadyUsedException.php(19): App\Exceptions\JsonApiException->__construct(Array)
#2 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Validators/UserValidator.php(58): App\Exceptions\Validation\User\EmailAlreadyUsedException->__construct()
#3 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Validators/UserValidator.php(32): App\Validators\UserValidator->validateEmail()
#4 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Routes/API/User/Create.php(39): App\Validators\UserValidator->validate()
#5 [internal function]: App\Routes\API\User\Create->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#6 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Handlers/Strategies/RequestResponse.php(41): call_user_func(Object(App\Routes\API\User\Create), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#7 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(325): Slim\Handlers\Strategies\RequestResponse->__invoke(Object(App\Routes\API\User\Create), Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response), Array)
#8 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\Route->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#9 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/Route.php(297): Slim\Route->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#10 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(443): Slim\Route->run(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#11 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/MiddlewareAwareTrait.php(116): Slim\App->__invoke(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#12 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(337): Slim\App->callMiddlewareStack(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#13 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/vendor/slim/slim/Slim/App.php(298): Slim\App->process(Object(Slim\Http\Request), Object(Slim\Http\Response))
#14 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/public/index.php(105): Slim\App->run()
#15 {main}
```

I'm really confused here, how is it showing the definition as `EmailAlreadyUsedException([string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]])`, when I've clearly implemented the constructor in `EmailAlreadyUsedException`, which takes no parameters?

**UPDATE**

I tried to debug and find out why $this->params["message"] is an array in the constructor of `JsonApiException`, but now I'm even more confused :

```
class JsonApiException extends AppException
{

    private $params = [
        "message" => "",
        "code" => 0,
        "previous" => null,
        "api" => [
            "message" => "",
            "code" => "",
            "status" => 200
        ]
    ];

    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        print_r($params);
        die;
        $this->params = array_merge_recursive($this->params, $params);
        parent::__construct($this->params["message"], 0, $this->params["previous"]);
    }

}
```

Result -> `Array ()`

Even though I'm passing

```
parent::__construct([
            "message" => "The e-mail provided by the exception has already been used",
            "api" => [
                "message" => "The provided e-mail address has already been used",
                "code" => "EmailAlreadyUsed"
            ],
            "previous" => null
        ]);
```

from `EmailAlreadyUsedException` to the constructor of `JsonApiException`, the $params array seems to arrive empty. Am I missing something again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long debugging sessions, the fault was not in the OOP behavior. It was in the function I was using to merge default parameters in `JsonApiException`. Instead of using `array_merge_recursive` which `merges the elements of one or more arrays together so that the values of one are appended to the end of the previous one`, I used `array_replace_recursive`.

When using `array_merge_recursive`, the $params property of the `JsonApiException` got assigned the value :

```
Array
(
    [message] => Array
        (
            [0] =>
            [1] => The e-mail provided by the exception has already been used
        )

    [code] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0
            [1] => 0
        )

    [api] => Array
        (
            [message] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] => The provided e-mail address has already been used
                )

            [code] => Array
                (
                    [0] =>
                    [1] => EmailAlreadyUsed
                )

            [status] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 200
                    [1] => 
                )

        )

)
```

Whereas, when using `array_replace_recursive`, the $params property becomes :

```
Array
(
    [message] => The e-mail provided by the exception has already been used
    [code] => 0
    [previous] =>
    [api] => Array
        (
            [message] => The provided e-mail address has already been used
            [code] => EmailAlreadyUsed
            [status] => 200
        )

)
```

Which in turn provided correct parameters to `\Exception::__construct()`.

Just one thing is weird though, although it works, when I try to do this :

```
class JsonApiException extends AppException
{

    private $params = [
        "message" => "",
        "code" => 0,
        "previous" => null,
        "api" => [
            "message" => "",
            "code" => "",
            "status" => 200
        ]
    ];

    public function __construct(array $params)
    {
        print_r($params);
        die;
        $this->params = array_replace_recursive($this->params, $params);
        parent::__construct($this->params["message"], 0, $this->params["previous"]);
    }

}
```

I'm still getting `Array ()`, which is weird because `array_replace_recursive` sets the corrects values.

Answer (score 3):

All of your exception classes call `parent::__construct`. This means, ultimately, the `\Exception` class constructor will get called. You are not providing the correct parameters for that constructor.

You can tell from your stacktrace:

> Trace: #0 /var/www/ElectroAbhi/app/Exceptions/JsonApiException.php(33): Exception->__construct(Array, 0, Array)

Your `EmailAlreadyUsedException` invokes the constructor of the `JsonApiException`, which invokes the constructor of PHP's native `\Exception` with `(Array, 0, Array)`, which is not what the constructor expects.

You have to fix these two lines:

```
 $this->params = array_merge_recursive($this->params, $params);
 parent::__construct($this->params["message"], 0, $this->params["previous"]);
```

Apparently, `$this->params["message"]` and `$this->params["previous"]` are arrays. But the params you pass to `parent::__construct` must match the signature

> [string $message [, long $code [, Throwable $previous = NULL]]]

Overriding a constructor in a derived class does not override the constructor in a parent class.

Comment: But I'm passing the correct parameters to the constructor of `\Exception` from `JsonApiException`? Overriding a constructor allows you to change it's definition, doesn't it?

Comment: @abishek The stack trace says you are passing an array, a number and an array, which is not what the signature of the parent constructor expects. Overriding a constructor in a derived class does not override the constructor in a parent class.

Comment: I tried to debug why `$this->params["message"]` is an array in the constructor and got totally new results. Can you please check my update?

Comment: @abhishek I cannot reproduce the `print_r($params)` to give an empty array. Don't know why you are getting this but the code you show in your question will not produce that.

Comment: The issue is solved, please see my answer. But yes, it's weird, print_r($params) still gives me an empty array, even though the `array_replace_recursive` is taking the correct values.